# Packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: linux, dependencies

So I understand that there are quite a few different posts about this topic. I have been to all of them and none of them are helping me with this problem. Could someone please help me out? Thank you in advance.

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libreadline6-dev : Depends: libtinfo-dev but it is not going to be installed
     libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.8.6-1) but 3.8.7.4-1 is to be installed
     libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1f-1ubuntu9.8) but 1.0.1f-1ubuntu11.4 is to be installed
                  Recommends: libssl-doc but it is not going to be installed
     libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.9.1+dfsg1-4ubuntu1) but 2.9.2+dfsg1-3 is to be installed
     libxslt1-dev : Depends: libxslt1.1 (= 1.1.28-2build1) but 1.1.28-2build2 is to be installed
     libyaml-dev : Depends: libyaml-0-2 (= 0.1.6-1ubuntu0.1) but 0.1.6-3 is to be installed
     sqlite3 : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.8.6-1) but 3.8.7.4-1 is to be installed
     zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Refer to this link `http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa`

Comment: Figured it out, just added a stable version of Ubuntu and deleted the old one. Had been meaning to do that anyway.